# I am unable to use SerializationUtils in my program

Tags: java, eclipse

I have added the jar file.zip by creating a new folder lib and also added it to BuildPath, yet it's not working. At the import statement, it's showing import statement can't be resolved.
[image]

Comment: No code, no error, no help.

Comment: Please provide the log of the errors, so we can understand what is wrong.

Comment: the error is import statement can't be resolved, even after i have added jar file in the project.

Comment: When posting question, take a look at its preview to see possible problems. In case of this question you should notice that your image was not added properly. Also this screenshot only confirms that you have some errors in import section, but we don't know what error it is, which jar you are talking about, and how did you add it.

Comment: well m really sorry for that.. I have added common-lang-2.6-bin as a jar file by creating a lib folder and then added it to the Buildpath.

Comment: Add this error message to your question. Also consider posting image of your project structure, which Jar you are referring to, and description letting us reproduce your steps of adding this jar (for now I only see ZIP)

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Eclipse, Java: How to import a library in zip-format?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14375810/eclipse-java-how-to-import-a-library-in-zip-format)

Answer (score 2):

From the screenshot it looks like you have added the ZIP file. Please unzip the file, you shall find a JAR file within it. Add it to the eclipse project and build path.

Comment: Actually,Eclipse should be able to use Jars from zip files without problem.

Comment: yes there are two jar files among which one is javadoc. so which one to add?

Comment: @Ayush the non javadoc, src one.

Comment: OK, it may depend on structure of ZIP file, but I am sure that there ware cases where I could simply import zip with library without problems. Probably this is not the case then.

Comment: @Pshemo a Java library can be bundled as a JAR or a ZIP (a JAR is also a ZIP file). That is not the case here. The ZIP file contains a JAR file and other information. It is a package. These can't be used as it is within Eclipse.

Comment: That could be it, or I may had installed some additional plugin to Eclipse which could handle it by searching for things like `[version].jar` or.`[version]-bin.jar` `[version]-src.jar` `[version]-doc.jar`. Don't remember now. Anyway you are right, I tried to add this ZIP and in standard Eclipse can't handle it correctly.

Comment: @Ayush re: KDM's comment: See [Accepting Answers: How does it work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/238021)